# How to conditional format if cell 1 is greater than 8 weeks

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I have the following;

```
Expected    Started
25/02/2020  01/01/2020
```

I want to conditionally format the 'Started' cell (`B2`) - So basically, the project deadline is the 25/2/20 - but it should be started 8 weeks in advance (by 31/12/19) so if the date is greater than 31/12/19 highlight red

I can't specify the date as there will be other dates later on, so i need to try and work out the formula, would someone be able to help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In google-sheets, you would apply the following custom formula onto your B column range:

```
=($A2-(7*8)) < $B2
```

See the below image:

[image]

Google-Sheets Example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sd59bd-fnKNTLoa7qQuBsEqFLki1uWNDLU9m7iOQemQ/edit?usp=sharing

How to article: https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/conditional-formatting-entire-row/

Answer (score 1):

try a simple custom formula like:

```
=B2>A2+56
```

[image: 0]